# Does having two sources of damage in one attack count as two damage rolls?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, damage

For instance, if an attack power allows you to do "*2d8+3 plus 1d6 fire damage*", and you're under the effects of a power which gives you *"+4 to  <s>all</s> damage rolls"*, would the +4 be added to both the normal damage and the fire damage, or just the normal damage?

For example, the Paladin Utility 6 (PHB) **Wrath of the Gods** says

> The targets add your Charisma modifier to damage rolls until the end of the encounter.

I was wondering if an attack which included two different types of damage roll would be affected twice, such as when the paladin is under the effects of **Bless Weapon** (DP, Paladin Utility 2):

> d6 extra radiant damage when hitting with the affected weapon

Comment: Closely related: [How does resist all apply to an attack that deals two types of (non-combined) damage?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25739/3548)

Comment: Ok so there's no specific power that you've come across that *actually* states "+X to ***all*** damage rolls"? I suspected as much. Wording can be very important when trying to clarify things so it's probably worth removing the *all* from your first sentence.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I'm not sure that's actually particularly relevant, since if it doesn't specify a restriction on _which_ damage rolls are affected, it would be all of them by default. IMO, the bigger problem in this situation is identifying what exactly constitutes a "damage roll."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damage rolls as referenced by most rule compendium usually refer to the damage caused by a single attack, no matter the damage types involved. The +4 applies to the overall damage (2d8 + 1d6 + 3) + 4 instead than each type individually. The only real exception to this would be if you caused 2d8+3 bludgeoning damage with your attack action, and then as an extra action you could also do an additional 1d6 fire damage, in which case I would rule that the +4 could apply separately to both, althought I have yet to see an ability which adds +4 to *all* types of damage. That said, this kind of action is not very well covered by most rulebooks and would ultimately be up to the DM.

Comment: 4e doesn't have a "bludgeoning" damage type. Considering that, and the fact that you haven't seen "an ability which adds +4 to _all_ types of damage" (which plenty of things in 4e do), along with your top tags, I suspect this was written with 3.5e or 5e mechanics in mind, which are very different from 4e mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly no. It is a single source of damage and so it counts as a single source of damage or a single damage roll.

Comment: So the fact that the additional damage (in this case) is from a separate power  has no impact on whether the two damage rolls within the one attack count as separate damage rolls, for the purposes of features/modifiers which boost damage rolls?

Comment: The exact wording of the second damage expression matters, whether it's extra damage or simply triggered by the original attack as a separate damage instance.

Answer (score 0):

### For Bless Weapon, No

Any time a power lets you roll additional dice for damage not included with the normal attack and it DOES NOT refer to this damage as "Extra Damage", you add your modifiers again. In this instance you used bless weapon which specifically refers to the damage as "extra radiant damage" which makes it a part of the original attack in terms of rolling.

For example the bard power Echoing Weapon from Heroes of the Feywild adds damage to the next attack a weapon makes but this damage is not classified as "Extra Damage" because of this any bonuses that can be applied more than once per turn are applied a second time for that attack.

> **Echoing Weapon** 
>   
> Encounter + Arcane, Thunder Minor Action Melee 1
>   
> Target: One weapon 
> Effect: Until the end of your next turn, the next
>   weapon attack made with the target weapon deals 2d6 thunder damage to
>   one target of the attack, regardless of whether the attack hits or
>   misses.

In comparison the Assassin's Strike power from Heroes of Shadow allows you to roll an extra 1d10 damage after you successfully hit a creature but this time the damage is referred to as "Extra Damage" and because of that the damage is considered to be part of the original attack and you only roll modifiers once.

> **Assassin's Strike** 
> Encounter Martial, No Action Personal 
> Special: Nothing but a short or extended rest can allow you to regain the use
>   of this power. 
> Trigger: You hit a creature within 5 squares of you
>   with an attack using a weapon. 
> Target: The creature you hit. 
> Effect:
>   The target takes 1d10 **extra damage** from the triggering attack. If the
>   target is helpless, this damage is maximized.

Comment: You're correct, but a little extra clarification: the reason Echoing Weapon isn't extra damage is because it only affects one target of the triggering attack. Since bursts and blasts roll damage once for all targets, Echoing Weapon couldn't be applied as extra damage without affecting all targets, and instead has to be a separate damage roll, which thus allows you to add relevant static bonuses again.